# convert mailbox message to PDF: which part?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to code a script that will export all my messages (mailbox mbox format) into PDF files with pdfkit.

It seems that all messages in my mailbox are multipart, and I'm struggling with figuring out which part is the relevant one. If I iterate through all parts with the code below, I will generate typically 3 to 5 PDFs per e-mail, with only one of them being similar to what I would see if I opened the e-mail with an e-mail client. The other parts are typically either raw text or something that looks like this: `x92O&S\xd2\x0c\xb4e\xee\x0fh\xc68\x1` (hexadecimal?).

I tried to solve the issue by including a test to filter for HTML (`if bool(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find())`) but it seems that this does not work.

```
for part in message.walk():
    partcounter +=1
    try:
        html = str(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        if bool(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find()):
            print(str(messagecounter)+'-'+str(partcounter)+' - '+"payload is HTML")
            filename = 'C:/Email_forwarding/Attachments/'+str(messagecounter)+"-"+str(partcounter)+'.pdf'#this keeps the file only for the last part, which seems to be correct
            pdfkit.from_string(html,filename, configuration=config)
            print(str(messagecounter)+'-'+str(partcounter)+' - '+"created %s" %(filename))
        else:
            print(str(messagecounter)+'-'+str(partcounter)+' - '+"payload is not HTML")
    except:
        print(str(messagecounter)+'-'+str(partcounter)+' - '+"no payload or failed to convert")
```

How can I detect which part of a multipart e-mail contains actual, interpretable HTML?

Comment: Have you tried `message.get_body(preferencelist=('html','plain'))`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body

Comment: It seems that get_body isn't a mailbox method. My message object has type mailbox.mboxMessage.

Comment: Why don't you do `if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':`?

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`part.get_content_type()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.get_content_type) to filter through the different parts of the message:

```
for part in message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
        html = str(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```